# Application.ScreenUpdating stops macro execution in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am not experienced VBA programmer, and I need community to find a problem with the Excel.

My problem is that in Excel, code stops execution immediatly after following line:
`Application.ScreenUpdating = True`

I use following example code from msdn website:

```
Dim elapsedTime(2) 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
For i = 1 To 2 
    If i = 2 Then Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    startTime = Time 
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate 
    For Each c In ActiveSheet.Columns 
        If c.Column Mod 2 = 0 Then 
            c.Hidden = True 
        End If 
    Next c 
    stopTime = Time 
    elapsedTime(i) = (stopTime - startTime) * 24 * 60 * 60 
Next i 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
MsgBox "Elapsed time, screen updating on: " & elapsedTime(1) & _ 
     " sec." & Chr(13) & _ 
     "Elapsed time, screen updating off: " & elapsedTime(2) & _ 
     " sec."
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193498.aspx

However, Msgbox never get executed, nor VBA shows any error - it just silently fails.

Anyidea why this is happening and how to fix that ?

Comment: works OK for me: did you add the code to a Sub in a Module?

Comment: Which event did you write this code in? I suggest to call the macro using a button click event to isolate the source of the error

Comment: Just pasted the code in a module and worked perfectly. why was the question upvoted??

Comment: Also, did you step through the code to determine the exact source of the execution fail?

Comment: Hello, I did step through the code, and it stops exactly on the line with Screenupdating = True.
However, I found the source of error - it was fail in function that do validation for auto-rules.  Fixed it, then code started to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, there was following problem, that didn't immediatly found at first glance:

- There is auto-validation rules in the Sheet
- Auto-validation rules are based on user-space function, i.e. code rule for matching is formula: `=NOT(IsValidCell(INDIRECT("RC";FALSE)))`
- there is a problem with this function.

Example of baqd code:

```
Function IsValidCell(ByVal CellValue As String) As Boolean
IsValidCell = False
If CellValue Like "#####" Then
    IsValidColumn = True ' Notice bug
Else ' Notice second bug
End Function
```

Result is that code in completely unseparated routine fails when excel tries to recalculate rules.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer; like earlier posters I am unable to get this routine to fail.

Firstly, I will say this is a dreadful piece of code.  I cannot understand why Microsoft posted something this bad.  For example:

- elapsedTime is not typed.  (It should be `Dim elapsedTime(2) As Double`)
- i, startTime and stopTime are not defined.
- The Activate is within the timed block for the first loop so, if Sheet1 is not the active sheet at the beginning, the time to activate it is added to the first loop's duration.
- The columns are not unhidden between the two loops so the second loop has nothing to do.  If you run the routine a second time, the two loops have the same duration.

There is a bug in Excel which I encounter very infrequently and not for a couple of years.  When I do encounter it, it takes me so long to discover the cause that I am behind schedule and forget to record the details for next time.  There are certain errors for which Excel does not stop and report the fault; instead it terminates the current function and continues with the next statement in the calling routine.  This subroutine has been called directly, so it would just stop without finishing.

My only suggestion is that there is something about this code on your Sheet1 on your computer that causes this error.

You seem to think the `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` statement is failing.  This is possible but unlikely.  From your description, all you know is that the routine does not reach the `MsgBox` statement.

I suspect `c.Hidden = True`.  I have seen a question asking about a maximum number of hidden columns but no one knew of a maximum.  One answer was you cannot hide part of a merged area but I cannot duplicate that error.  Look at your Sheet1: are some even columns hidden but not all?  Unhide the columns and try again.  Does the routine fail at a consistent column?  Does it fail after hiding something like 1,024 columns?

I wish you luck with any investigation.  However, I suggest you abandon this deadful code and accept that `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` will reduce the run time of any routine that updates the active worksheet.

Comment: As you imagined, there was a problem with the code on Sheet1. More information below.

Comment: @oleg.  Glad you found the cause.